# Is there an efficient way to tell which parts of my startup of Emacs take the longest to load?

Tags: init-file, start-up, performance, profiler

I have been trying to make the start-up times better. Almost all of my init.el is broken into use-package declarations like this:

```lisp
(use-package x ...)
(use-package y ...)
(use-package z ...)
```

I want to start optimising those parts of the init.el that take the longest. Is there a way to do something like,

```lisp
(use-package x ...)
; print load time for x
(use-package y ...)
; print load time for y
(use-package z ...)
; print load time for z
```

I know for the entire file you can do something like this `(message (time-subtract after-init-time before-init-time))`

Comment: Have you tried customising `use-package-verbose` and `use-package-minimum-reported-time`?

Comment: I did not know they existed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does it:

```lisp
(setq
  use-package-verbose t
  use-package-minimum-reported-time 0)
```

We get in `*Messages*`:

```
Loading package x...done (0.021s)
Configuring package x...done (0.020s)
Loading package y...done (0.025s)
Configuring package y...done (0.020s)
Loading package z...done (0.041s)
Configuring package z...done (0.020s)
```